# calculate the complexity of binary search algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, binary-search

How do i calculate the complexity of this algorithm at the best case and its complexity at the worst case and the average complexity by assuming that the probability that the element is in the list is 0≤p≤1 and that all sites are equal probability

Comment: It seems like some information is missing. What is *this algorithm*? What input are you running it on?

Comment: That's three (underspecified) questions. please restrictiy yourself to one. Also, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?